# Cookie value is messy code in IE

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2

I develop a web by using ASP.NET MVC2. Creating the cookie in the background. Then I want to get the cookie value in IE by using javaScript,but the value is messy code when I set it in chinese.

```
document.cookie:

userID=1017030057 userName=涓浗
```

Then I check the cookie in my computer.It is normal:

**userID
1017030057**
localhost/
1536
3361761792
30304298
1345470592
30230873
*
**userName
中国**
localhost/
1536
3361761792
30304298
1345470592
30230873
*
ID
22
localhost/
1536
3361761792
30304298
1345470592
30230873
*

This case only happen in IE. In other browser, the cookie value is normal.
My IE is IE8. The page headers conforms the IE charset issue, and presents normal in chinese except the cookie value.

Comment: have a look at your text encoding and page headers, it looks like its charset issue in IE

Comment: @Alex  It is conform. The page presents normal by using chinese except Geting the value from the cookie. Thank you for you reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try encoding the cookie on server side and use `decodeURIComponent(cookieValue)` in JS. let me know if that works

Comment: Thank you. It works. I did not encode the cookie on server side. It means that the "document.cookie" do decoding in IE?

Comment: I may do not express exactly. " I did not encode the cookie on server side",it means that I did not encode the cookie before asking this " messy code" question. Now I have encoded on server side. The cookie is not messy code by using decodeURIComponent(cookieValue).